# Meu insert não cadastra os dados no mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Galera, estou tentando inserir alguns dados no meu bd, eu já fiz essa ação em outros sistemas e sempre deu certo, porém dessa vez não está dando, ele não mostra nenhuma mensagem de erro, ele só não inclui no banco, tentei fazer o insert de outras maneiras porém não funcionou (o código de baixo é o da última tentativa que fiz), dei um echo no sql e ele está certo, ele simplesmente só não adiciona os cadastros no banco, os nomes estão todos corretos, teriam como ajudar? obrigado desde já.

```
<?php
    include_once "conexao.php";
    //include_once "defines.php";
    //require_once('classes/BD.class.php');
    //BD::conn();

    if(isset($_POST['prox'])){
        $nome = 'Giovani';
        $data = strip_tags(trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'data', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
        $sala = '1';
        $computador = 's';
        $projetor = 's';
        $som = 's';
        $microfone = 'n';

        if (empty($data)) {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="erro">* Atenção, para prosseguir é preciso selecionar uma data. *</div>';
            }else{
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO `agendamento` (`nome`, `data`, `sala`, `computador`, `projetor`, `som`, `microfone`) VALUES ('$nome', '$data', '$sala', '$computador', '$projetor', '$som', '$microfone');";
                    $qur = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
                    echo $sql;
                }
            }           
?>
```

Comment: Desculpa. Bom, você sabe a versão anterior que voce usava nos bancos e a versão atual ?

Comment: Leia sobre a função [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: No código postado não há erros, reproduzi no meu servidor e funcionou direito. Coloque na pergunta os outros códigos envolvidos na questão. ou seja, conexao.php,  HTML.

Comment: tenho esse código de conexão:<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "Admin", "admin", "agendamento_equipamentos") or die ("Erro ao conectar com o banco de dados!");
?>

Comment: A versão do banco é a mesma que usava antes

Comment: usei o mysqli_error e ele retornou essa menssagem: incorrect date value: '30/01/2018' for column 'data' at row 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, no meu código estou usando o datepicker, e ele formata a data para o padrão br e meu mysql só tava aceitando o padrão en, já fiz as adaptações e está tudo certo agora.